# Language Change Update Issue in Different Tabs

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, flutter-navigation

I'm working on a Flutter project where I've implemented a tab bar interface using the `CupertinoTabScaffold`. Each tab corresponds to a different page, and I have a language selection feature in one of the tabs (let's call it `test1.dart`). The issue I'm facing is that when I change the language in `test1.dart`, the language update doesn't automatically propagate to the other tabs (`test2.dart` and `test3.dart`).

In `test1.dart`, I'm using the `setState` function to update the selected language, which updates the UI in that tab. However, the changes don't reflect in the other tabs unless I manually refresh them.

Here's a simplified overview of my code structure:

- `test_tab_bar.dart`: Contains the tab bar setup and tab builders.
- `test1.dart`: Contains the language selection logic and UI.
- `test2.dart`: Displays a component that should reflect the selected language.
- `test3.dart`: Similar to `test2.dart`, should also display the selected language.

I'm using a global variable for the selected language and importing it into `test2.dart` and `test3.dart`.

What's the recommended approach to ensure that the language change in `test1.dart` updates automatically in the other tabs without requiring manual refreshes?

Here's the relevant part of my code in `test1.dart`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

String selectedBrandNameLanguageOption = 'English'; // Default selection

final List<String> brandNameLanguageOptions = ['English', "Arabic - العربية"];

String getBrandName() {
  return selectedBrandNameLanguageOption == 'English' ? 'Star' : 'نجمة';
}

class TestPage1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestPage1({super.key});

  @override
  State<TestPage1> createState() => _TestPage1State();
}

class _TestPage1State extends State<TestPage1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(getBrandName())),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text("Selected language is ${selectedBrandNameLanguageOption}"),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                selectedBrandNameLanguageOption = brandNameLanguageOptions[1];
              });
            },
            child: Text("Change Language to Arabic"),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                selectedBrandNameLanguageOption = brandNameLanguageOptions[0];
              });
            },
            child: Text("Change Language to English"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here's how I'm using the language in `test2.dart`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:project_ammam/test1.dart';

class TestPage2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestPage2({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(getBrandName()),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here's how I'm using the language in `test3.dart`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:project_ammam/test1.dart';

class TestPage3 extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestPage3({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(getBrandName()),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its because in tabview tabs are loaded already you should store the value locally and fetch it from there instead of setstate.

use this package for local storage: https://pub.dev/packages/hive_flutter